# Possible to run views_embed_view() for a specific role

Tags: views, users, theming

Without having to `user_load(SOME_UID_THAT_HAS_MY_INTENED_ROLES);` and swap the current `$user` object and then replace it.

Is it possible to say,

```
views_embed_view('view_of_articles');
```

But tell it to respect the permissions of a certain array of roles like,

```
views_embed_view('view_of_articles', array(SOME_RID));
```

I know the above wont work since the function isn't defined in such a way, but could this be possible with `theme()` functions, or something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

In view check the option of "Access" and select roles. Now even if you call the view with views_embed_view() It wont display if the user is not part of the role that have access.

Comment: Nope that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. For example, when your an admin and you've got contextual links turned on and you look at a view, you see the extra markup and the hovering states. Or imagine a field that is permissioned for certain roles, but you print the view as an admin while you want the view to look like it was for a certain role.

Comment: Have you check this module : http://drupal.org/project/roleswitcher It might help.

Comment: Yea I'm also aware of those types of modules, but I don't want to see the whole experience as the other role, just the view in question.